# How to cancel outgoing call in android dev.?

Tags: android, call

I just want to know if how to cancel outgoing call in android dev.? Is it possible in the simplest way of coding?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `BroadCastReceiver` that will be called on the action : `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`

Java Class :

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){
            setResultData(null);
            abortBroadcast(); // cancel the call
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest declaration

**Edit** 
don't forget add out going permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" /> 

<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

With this code, any call will be canceled and you will not be able to do a call if this app is on your phone

Comment: it is not cancelling the call!! I tested on Android 4.2 device. Also, simply calling `abortBroadcast()` won't help i guess as it only Sets the flag indicating that this receiver should abort the current broadcast. NO Way it is supposed to "CANCEL" call

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a BroadcastReceiver with a priority of 0.

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="0" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
```

2.In the BroadcastReceiver intercept the ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent in its onReceive method

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){
            setResultData(null);
        }
    }
```

3.call `setResultData(null)` in the onReceive as shown in above code/method

Add below permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```